# Deserialize protobuf json using DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, protobuf-net, datacontractjsonserializer

I will give a shot asking here as seemingly simple question but hard to find answer.. maybe for some people this is a common sense..

When one microservice uses Protobuf to build classes and serialize in json,  can another microservice deserialize this json format using classic DataContract Deserializer?

Comment: Your question is tagged [tag:datacontractjsonserializer] but your title says `DataContractSerializer` which is an XML serializer, not a JSON serializer.  Can you confirm you really mean `DataContractJsonSerializer`?

Comment: If so, then why not give it a try?  The [docs for `DataContractJsonSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer?view=net-7.0#remarks) state, *For most scenarios that involve serializing to JSON and deserializing from JSON, we recommend the APIs in the `System.Text.Json` namespace.* but the serializer has been ported to .NET Core and does work in straightforward cases so the simple answer to your question would seem to be **yes, you can use `DataContractJsonSerializer` to deserialize well-formed JSON.**

Comment: It is, however, much less flexible than System.Text.Json and (especially) Json.NET so you might run into problems in practice.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: I was more of doubting on the protobuf spec if serialized json is plain enough and can be deserialized into [DataContract] attributed .net classes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute?view=net-7.0